# How do I toggle word-wrap in a EditBox

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7, common-controls, microsoft-common-controls

How can I toggle word-wrap in a multiline EditBox?

I can create it with or without but I don't know which message I should use to toggle the wrapping mode.

Comment: Word-wrapping is controlled by a word-break procedure set by the [`EM_SETWORDBREAKPROC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/em-setwordbreakproc) window message. Or, maybe you are thinking of "soft" word-wrapping? That is set using the [`EM_FMTLINES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/em-fmtlines) window message. See [Handling Wordwrap and Line Breaks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/edit-controls-text-operations#handling-wordwrap-and-line-breaks) for more details.

Comment: For EM_FMTLINES MSDN says: "It has no effect on the display of the text within the edit control". It is only for the actual buffer used by WM_GETTEXT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EditBox does not support toggling word-wrap. There is no message you can send and you cannot change the window style because [MSDN says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/edit-control-styles):

> After the control has been created, these styles cannot be modified, except as noted.

Your only option is to create a new control with the desired style (`WS_HSCROLL|ES_AUTOHSCROLL`), copy the text into the new control and then destroy the old control.

On Windows 2000 and later you can use `EM_GETHANDLE`+`EM_SETHANDLE` to swap the buffers without having to make a copy of the text.

Answer (score 1):

Standard Windows control EDITBOX doesn't support toggling word wrap.

Notepad simulates it by creating new EDITBOX and destroying old one. You could verify this with Spy++. Observe how window handle changes after you toggle word wrap.